# How do I reset titlesec spacing?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

I am aware that it is possible to change the spacing before and after sections using the titlesec package. That's great. I changed it, but I want to reset it later in the document to the defaults. How do I do that? MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{1.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.1ex plus .2ex}


\begin{document}

\section{This is great}
\subsection{This is great too}

Now I want to restore section and subsection spacing

%% need some reset command here

\subsection{Not so great}

How to reset the spacing for this one to whatever the defaults were?


\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a "switch" to turn everything back to default. However, in the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) p. 24 sec. 8.2, you have snippets for default formats.